# Why wamp localhost keeps showing me notices?

Tags: php, localhost, mariadb, wamp

I had problems with localhost in wampserver when, I accidentally deleted the wamplangues folder.

I download it from here https://github.com/phlyper/wamp-conf/tree/master/wamp/www/wamplangues

but it's keeps showing me errors like:

> Notice: Undefined index: versmaria in C:\wamp64\www\index.php on line
>   275 Notice: Undefined index: mariaportUsed in C:\wamp64\www\index.php
>   on line 276 Undefined index: docmaria in C:\wamp64\www\index.php on
>   line 276

I searched in the index.php file and I saw that this is related to the langues folder... do you have any ideas about that? I'm stucked!

Comment: Might be because of faulty installation. try re-installing.

Comment: @MebinJoe this is my very last solution... :/

Comment: That comment didn't really help us. Have you tried completely removing Wamp and installing it again or not?

Comment: Why not fix the errors instead of hiding them?

Comment: What version of WAMPServer are you using?

Comment: **I dont think that Repo has got anything to do with the Official WAMPServer**

Comment: Install the version of WAMPServer you are using on another PC. Copy the relevant folder. Uninstall WAMPServer from the other PC

Comment: @RiggsFolly 3.1.4!

Comment: @mickmackusa thank you, but it's irrelevant with my code... it an existing .php file in wamp server!

Comment: Then try the above comment route. That stuff you found on github looks rather older than that

Comment: @MagnusEriksson no, i didn't try this, cause Ι think it's a trouble, with files etc..

Comment: @RiggsFolly installing wamp server in another pc and copy the related folder?

Comment: You could try upgrading to 3.1.7 [from here](http://wampserver.aviatechno.net/) that MIGHT replace the language files, but thats a guess

Comment: @RiggsFolly thank you very much for your solution to install wamp in another computer!It worked!!
I have one last thing to ask you: why can't I browse in my projects directly from my home page in wamp? It shows me that it couldn't load it..so,
I have to write my project as a path localhost/project in my browser...is this right?

Comment: You need to setup a Virtual Hosts, dont worry its not difficult, there is a link on the WAMPServer homepage called **Add a Virtual Hosts** Click it follow the instructions on the page. [Also see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665064/project-links-do-not-work-on-wamp-server/23990618#23990618) It should help you understand WHY and HOWTO

Comment: thank you so very much @RiggsFolly :)